# How to change vsftpd to IPv4?

Tags: sftp, vsftpd, ftps

I am setting up two vsftp service running on port 21 and port 990. Can someone show me how I can change it to IPv4 instead of current IPv6? I can't find a way to change the setting to IPv4. Below is screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/371743/117549 would be helpful?

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152612/netstat-why-are-ipv4-daemons-listening-to-ports-listed-only-in-a-inet6

Answer (score 1):

From vsftpd.conf

```
# This directive enables listening on IPv6 sockets. By default, listening
# on the IPv6 "any" address (::) will accept connections from both IPv6
# and IPv4 clients. It is not necessary to listen on *both* IPv4 and IPv6
# sockets. If you want that (perhaps because you want to listen on specific
# addresses) then you must run two copies of vsftpd with two configuration
# files.
# Make sure, that one of the listen options is commented !!
listen_ipv6=YES
```

IOW unless you want to disable IPv6 there's no need to change anything.